# My MongoDB CPU usage becomes 100 percent when doing multiple queries at a specific time

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB 3.4, facing the issue when do multiple request at a time.

For Example if I do 1000 request at 200 sec, at that time MongoDB CPU usage will be around 98 - 100 percent, and at that time CPU is completely choked and returns failure of system.

What should be the good approach for solving this. I used replica set which runs on :

primary: port 27017

slave: port 27018

arbiter: port 27019

System Configuration : Windows 10 (4 VCPU, 8GB Ram, 1 TB Harddisk)
Any suggestion/help will be really appreciated.

Comment: You are likely missing some proper indexes to reduce the amount of BSON parsing.

Comment: You're also running three separate `mongod` processes in one machine. This is not a recommended setup, since any reasonable workload will overwhelm the machine due to the resource contention between the two data-bearing `mongod` processes.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha so if I fetch any data for primary then also it takes time to return the response due to replication??? If yes then what will be the good approach for setup the replication

Comment: @Abhay replication is designed to be run in separate hosts. One `mongod` was designed to run in one machine. That is, you can run multiple `mongod` inside one machine, but once the workload hits a reasonable level, you cannot expect great performance due to resource contention. Remember that the secondary do as much work as the primary since it has to replicate writes quickly. If this is a dev environment, it's fine to run multiple `mongod` to test how a replica set setting will affect your app. However this is not a proper setup to run a stress test.